# Integration by parts, hyperbolic functions

Tags: calculus, hyperbolic-functions

I tried solving this hyperbolic integration using integration by parts, and it doesn’t seem to work.
$$ \begin{gather} \int \sinh ^ { 2 } u d u \\ = \sinh u \cosh u - \cosh ^ { 2 } u \end{gather} $$
But this is the actual solution:
$$ \frac { 1 } { 2 } ( - x + \frac { 1 } { 2 } \sinh ( 2 x ) ) + C$$
I know I could do this using identities or write it in terms of $e$, but why does this not work?
Thank you so much!

Comment: Integration by parts ($\sinh u$ and $\sinh u\,\mathrm{d}u$) gives you $\int\sinh^2u\,\mathrm{d}u=\sinh u\cosh u-\int\cosh^2 u\,\mathrm{d}u$, not $\sinh u\cosh u-\cosh^2u$.

Comment: In fact, since $\cosh^2=\sinh^2+1$, this does give you a solution.

Comment: that yields an equation for $\int \sinh^2 x dx$

Comment: Oh right thanks for your answers! My mistake